# No logs get logged into syslog file after i removed all lines from it

Tags: 14.04, syslog

I deleted all lines from my /var/log/syslog as this file had grown to a large file.

But after this activity now no logs get logged into it.
I think i deleted some lines responsible for logs settings, if i have done so kindly help me to restore it to its initial state or even i get to know what a default syslog file contains, it wwould be helpful in setting the things right.

Comment: it is ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS system.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the system logger with

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

What logs get written to which log files are controlled by `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*`, which I hope you didn't mess with.